# Bash Curl request not sending complete parameter

Tags: bash, curl, post

I have the following small bash script:

```
TEST=$(curl -X POST -s -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://$SITE/REST/v1/ -d '
{
    "Authorization":"Bearer '$TOKEN'"
}
' --trace-ascii /dev/stdout)
```

In this case, $TOKEN=c4cc0c81e279defd4bd261e9e1550e8a1ded5JKg5

However, when I send the request with --trace-ascii enabled, I can see the following in the output:

```
{. "Authorization":"Bearer "c4cc0c81e279defd4bd261e9 0040: e1550e8a1ded5JKg5"". }
```

Any reason why this gets split up? How can I prevent this?

Comment: Maybe the variable `TOKEN` is already set to the truncated value?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue when I use Bearer c4cc0c81e279defd4bd261e9e1550e8a1ded5JKg5 in plain text. It also gets cut off

Comment: i think the problem is on the ' '$TOKEN' '  in this way the only word non single quoted is $TOKEN

Comment: Maybe this behaviour is due to shell quoting rules. Try to save your post data into a file and specify it on the command line `-d @post.json`

Comment: Count your single quotes. Do you actually want single quotes embedded in the data you post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this, which will help with the quoting:

```
data=$(printf '{"Authorization":"Bearer %s"}' "$TOKEN")
output=$(curl -s -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://$SITE/REST/v1/ -d "$data" --trace-ascii /dev/stdout)
```

I suspect you may need to send Authorization as a header not as data. Try this, it's quite readable

```
curl_opts=(
    --silent
    --header "Content-type: application/json"
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $token"
    --trace-ascii -
)
curl "${curl_opts[@]}" -X POST -d "$other_data" "$url"
```

Note you should get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES: leave those as reserved for the shell.

Comment: Thank you! How would the data printf part look like if I would need to pass two key-value?

Comment: At a bash prompt, enter `help printf`